# Convert docx to byte[] and save it to the disk using File.WriteAllBytes

Tags: c#, docx

I am reading a docx file using  `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` lib.
I am manipulating the file and need to write it to the disk.
Doing this using the openxml lib is no brainer, the problem is that I need to pass the file content (`byte[]`) to a different API in my code and this API is handling the save operation.
This api is using `File.WriteAllBytes`. When I try to save my file via `File.WriteAllBytes` I get XML inside the doc instead of the doc read content.
How can I extract the byte[] from the doc and save it to the disc using `File.WriteAllBytes`

```
var path = "path/to/doc.docx";
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true))
{
    string docText = null;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
    {
        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    docText = new Regex("BBB").Replace(docText, "CCC!");
    // here i will manipuldate docText
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
        WordprocessingDocument.Create(ms , WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
        Body body = new Body(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(docText))));
        mainPart.Document = new Document(body);
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes("path/to/cloned.docx", ms.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Do you need to manipulate the doc file?? Or you only want to read and save the file??

Comment: @Hadi I am able to manipulate the file. I can't write it to the disc via `File.WriteAllBytes`

Comment: I know you can. My question is that do you **NEED** to open the file using `WordProcessingDocument`?? Why don't you open it using `File`?

Comment: @Hadi Ahhh, because im using `WordProcessingDocument` to manipulate the file. once I'm done, I need to write via `File.WriteAllBytes`. thanks!

Comment: Here's your problem: `docText` isn't the document text, it's the raw XML of the entire file.  Your line `Body body = new Body(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(docText))));` is turning all that raw XML into a single text run.

Comment: @jgfооt any chance for a code sample of how to implement that? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick:

(tested with [SampleDoc.docx from Github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-Get-Set-EditOpen-XML/blob/fbfdfdb7f55f0e3d570385bf77da031457c18111/C%23/WD_OpenXML_js/SampleDoc.docx?raw=true))

```
var path = @"path/to/doc.docx";

byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
    {
        Body body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
        foreach (var text in body.Descendants<Text>())
        {               
            text.Text = text.Text.Replace("BBB", "CCC!");
        }
        wordDoc.Close();
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes(path+".mod.docx", stream.ToArray());
}
```

debug output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! you example is working but not replacing the text... because in runtime `body.Descendants<Text>()` is empty, can you please look into that?

Comment: it works very well with my quite plain example docx file. may be your docx is very special crafted?! Can you provide it as a template somehow?

Comment: @fatnjazzy see my edit and linked sample word file.  I used `text.Text = text.Text.Replace("the", "THE");` in that case

Comment: Here is my doc: https://filebin.net/1kicxixtj3gtq3ev/SampleDoc.zip?t=wa7fxo53 again, it is not going in the foreach loop. thank you for your time!

Comment: it's replacing the BBB in the first line as expected. Tested with LinqPad 5 and OpenXML Nuget Package v 2.9.1

Comment: Added debug output. as you can see, it's iterating through all lines. any restrictions on file level? Are you executing locally or on a server within IIS or azure?

Comment: Ok. working. I have to re-arrange my `using` statements. thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to manipulate the raw XML, so you actually shouldn't use `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` at all--just treat your docx like the raw ZIP file that it is.  Here is some sample code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

public static byte[] Change(string path)
{
    // Make a temporary directory
    var myTempDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Join(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName() ));
    myTempDir.Create();

    // Extract all the XML files in the docx to that temporary directory
    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(path))
        zipArchive.ExtractToDirectory(myTempDir.FullName);

    // Read in the main document XML
    FileInfo docFile = new FileInfo(Path.Join(myTempDir.FullName, "word", "document.xml"));
    string rawXML = File.ReadAllText(docFile.FullName);

    // Manipulate it-- warning, this could break the whole thing
    rawXML = rawXML.Replace("winter", "spring");

    // Save the manipulated xml back over the old file
    docFile.Delete();
    File.WriteAllText(docFile.FullName, rawXML);

    // Zip our temporary directory back into a docx file
    FileInfo tempFile = new FileInfo(Path.GetTempFileName());
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(myTempDir.FullName, tempFile.FullName);

    // Read the raw bytes in from our new file
    byte[] rawBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(tempFile.FullName);

    return rawBytes;

}
```

You might want to delete all those temp files, too--but I'll leave that part to you.